# Log of all connections/queries via Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I'm working on optimizing an app that interfaces with Parse.com and was wondering if anyone knew of a way to monitor/log all connections and/or queries executed.

I've looked through the documentation and clicked around and can't see anything readily available so hoping someone can help.

Thanks